# I've used composer to install drupal - why do I still have unresolved php dependencies?

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php

I'm trying to build a `drupal` webserver using `composer`, which I am told is the right way to do it.

The command I've used to install drupal is this:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev --stability dev mysite --no-interaction
```

However, when I start my `apache` server I get a bunch of errors about missing libraries, functions, etc. I can resolve these by googling each one and installing the required php library - but isn't composer supposed to do this for me? According to [the composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md);

> Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to
>   declare the libraries your project depends on and it will manage
>   (install/update) them for you.

When I navigate to the `mysite/vendor` directory I see a bunch of drupal-related packages, but as far as I can tell these are only drupal dependencies, not php dependencies. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion here comes from the word 'libraries'.

Composer is a tool for dependency management *written* in PHP.

PHP itself relies on a scripting engine (originally [Zend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Engine), but there are alternatives like Facebook's [HHVM](https://hhvm.com/), etc.), it works as a compiler and runtime engine and it needs 'libraries' - think of it as *modules* or *extensions*. These modules are mostly written in C, some in C++.

Having 'missing libraries' errors when Apache starts up does not mean Composer has missed any Drupal dependencies, it means PHP needs to be configured or rebuilt properly with the missing modules.

There are 3 types of modules ([PHP's extensions membership](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/extensions.membership.php)):

- Core modules that cannot be left out of a PHP binary with compilation options.
- Core extension modules that are bundled with PHP core but not necessarily enabled.
- External modules that are not bundled with PHP core. These modules are available from a repository called [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/) (PHP Extension Community Library).

For example, if you were to speedup Drupal or any PHP applications by caching both PHP code and user variables, you would need some opcode like [APC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php). That said, adding APC settings to php.ini would not work as is without the corresponding module being compiled with PHP.